# Website not loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a new web developer, and at the suggestion of Richard Bovell at [JavaScript is Sexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/), I've decided to test my skills by making a... well, test!

I did the basic HTML, and I've written a function to display any given question, and it works perfectly in JSFiddle.

However when I test it with PHPStorm (run it with my browser), it seems like the JavaScript/jQuery is not loading.

In fact, when I use Chrome's error console, jQuery.min says, "failed to load resources."

I'm using this code in my source:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I've also tried using this source:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>`

but also not loading resource.

As a result, my entire JavaScript code is not working since it was jQuery based.

If I load the link into my web browser it works perfectly fine, so it doesn't seem like a network error.

Edit:

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/3CY7g/

And the error reads:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:2
(anonymous function) script.js:2
Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js`

Can anyone give me some pointers as to why jQuery isn't loading? Thanks!

Edit 2: Got the answer. http: is required! Thanks!

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with the code so we can see the error.

Comment: You need a server to resolve `//`. You can make it work by specifying the protocol yourself `http:`

Comment: `my entire JavaScript code is not working since it was jQuery based`.. its other way round

Comment: the url is perfectly valid. ensure the protocol of your website and the jquery url matches. can you check in console what error do you get?

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/3CY7g/ 

And the error reads: 

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:2
(anonymous function) script.js:2
Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You were not entering a valid URL

Comment: Well, it is valid, but not in OPs context. `//` resolves to the protocol being used.

Comment: Adding http: worked perfectly! I was running it client-side and not running it on a server, so I imagine that if I upload everything to a server it'll work with just // . Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When testing a file locally, i.e. not running it from an actual server, you need to specify the `http://` or `https://`. So change:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```